# How can i duplicate a Wordpress/Woocommerce plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

How can i duplicate a Wordpress/Woocommerce plugin so that there are two of the same plugins running at same time.

i would need this for product barcode/EAN numbers.
the reason is i sell some products that can have different EAN since some are from EU an other imported from US, that make it have 2 barcodes even its same product.

can someone help me with that please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Why would you duplicate a whole _plugin_ for that, and what exactly would you expect the outcome to be? IMHO this should be done by adding a custom field, maybe using ACF, and then hooking into the WP/WooCommerce filter system, wherever a EAN/Barcode needs to be shown based on location.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve can be done using Variable product option on woocommerce.

Variable product option offers you to have unique SKU for each sub product along with unique pricing and features. Then customize the website around those options.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).